# Multiple modals can only close 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to make multiple modals on my website however I can only close the last one of the three even though they have 3 seperate functions with 3 different classes.

How do I make it so that each modal i opened by it's appropriate button and closed when you click out of the modal window.

HTML

```
<div class="container flex bg-black-opacity mt-40 rounded pt-10 pb-12 mb-10 mx-auto items-center">
        <div class="container ml-5 cursor-pointer" id='1btn'>
            <img src="assets/img/merch-1.png" alt="" style='height: 400px;' class='shadow-pink'>
            <p class='uppercase mt-4 text-white'>Vice Versa 2020 Heather Grey Sweatshirt</p>
            <p class="text-white mt-4 ml-1 text-2xl">£15.00</p>

        </div>
        <div id="1mdl" class="modal1">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container ml-5 cursor-pointer" id='2btn'>
            <img src="assets/img/merch-2.png" alt="" style='height: 400px;' class='shadow-pink'>
            <p class='uppercase mt-4 text-white'>Vice Versa 2020 Heather Grey Sweatshirt</p>
            <p class="text-white mt-4 ml-1 text-2xl">£15.00</p>

        </div>
        <div id="2mdl" class="modal2">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container ml-5 cursor-pointer" id='3btn'>
            <img src="assets/img/merch-3.png" alt="" style='height: 400px;' class='shadow-pink'>
            <p class='uppercase mt-4 text-white'>Vice Versa 2020 Heather Grey Sweatshirt</p>
            <p class="text-white mt-4 ml-1 text-2xl">£15.00</p>

        </div>
        <div id="3mdl" class="modal3">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .modal1 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal2 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal3 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

JavaScript

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById("1mdl");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("2mdl");
var modal3 = document.getElementById("3mdl");

var btn1 = document.getElementById("1btn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("2btn");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("3btn");

btn1.onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}
btn3.onclick = function() {
  modal3.style.display = "block";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reassigning the click event overrides the previous binded callback function

simply use this (kept it simplified as it is in the original question)

```
 window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    } else if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    } else
    if (event.target == modal3) {
        modal3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are **overwriting** `window.onlick` again & again by *reassigning*
>   it.

**Add below lines**

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (
   event.target.id == modal1.id ||
   event.target.id == modal2.id ||
   event.target.id == modal3.id
  ) {
    document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Remove below lines**

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0u5aLtd6/1/)

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! So the new code just assigns the same onclick function to all 3 modals isntead of overtwriting them?

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use window.onlick 3 times. Just use a common class for all modal like "modal" and change in the css as well. Use window.oncick to check whether target has class "modal" if true then display none.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if(event.target.classList.contains("modal")){
    event.target.style.display="none"; 
  }  
}
```

Details in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/atiqul052/pen/WNvgbyZ)